# Merge CSV files after deleting first row from each file

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I have Multiple CSV files in a folder with 1st uncommon row. Column name starts from 2nd row which is common in all the CSV files. I am trying to delete the first row from each CSV file and Merge it.

code:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(readr)
  df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
    df<-df[-1] %>%
    lapply(read_csv) %>% 
    bind_rows
```

Comment: Specify what the specific problem you are having is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem:  you are misusing the pipe `%>%`.

First, since you are using a `dplyr` pipe chain to create a variable `df`, you can't refer to `df` inside your pipes.  So the code

```
df <- step1.do_something() %>% step2.do_something_with_df() %>% step3.etc()
```

is doomed to fail in step 2.

Second, it is not possible to have an assignment `df <- ...` within the pipe, standing on its own the way you've done it.  My solution is to `lapply` a function which drops the first row from a dataframe or tibble.

Third, the pipe steps go left to right (or top to bottom, the way you've formatted your code).  So you'll need to perform the drop-the-first-row step AFTER you've read the csv file.

Finally, you drop a row from a dataframe `d` with `d = d[-1,]`, not `d = d[-1]`.

So what you're trying to do should look like this:

```
df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  lapply(function(d) d[-1,]) %>%  
  bind_rows
```

I really like the way you use `list.files`, `read_csv` and the pipe to read and clean a bunch of files in one line of code.  You just made a mistake around the part where you drop the first line of each file.

Comment: One can use the `skip=1` option with read_csv to remove the second `lapply` call: `df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply( function(x) {read_csv(x, skip=1)})  %>%  
  bind_rows`

Comment: Even better, @Dave2e !